# Who manages Ubuntu packages?

Tags: 12.04, server, package-management

2 packages available for Ubuntu Server 12.04 that I've come across are horribly out of date: Nginx and phpMyAdmin. I use PPAs to manage these, but I've often wondered why these packages are so out of date while others are not (PHP5, MySQL, for example).

Comment: Add `qemu` to your list.  As of 2014 it's at version 1.0 from 2008!  Come on Ubuntu!

Comment: I use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) as SOP before installing anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Ubuntu MOTU ("Masters of the Universe")](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU) team does.

They have to balance stability and using backported patches against using a new version and risking introducing bugs (in your case to a stable LTS version). They also have to prioritize what is important and to spend time on trying to update without breaking that package.

It could just be a case of not being familiar enough with a piece of software to know the kirks that could break it, so they may leave it to the "pro's" for that piece of software to make a PPA.

And, of course, I'm sure they would always love to have more help, but it may not always be feasible for everyone (depending on what they know) to jump in and fix the things that are bothering them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Given how old those packages I mentioned are, they should really just remove them from the repositories as they are largely a security risk at this point, which leads me to wonder how many other packages are in the same state, and why bother to have such old packages at all - keep the maintained ones, drop outdated ones.

Comment: @Paul I'm not super familiar with the particular packages (and the associated risks) but I think that is what the different repositories are about. IIRC, `main` is supposed to be updated (and officially supported by Canonical) while `universe` is maintained by volunteers and may or may not always be up to date.